# C# program not displaying output value

Tags: c#, textbox

```
public partial class Form1: Form {
    // Define a few variables
    int InputInteger;
    int HoldInteger;
    int OutputInteger;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Used to close the form when exit is clicked
        this.Close();
    }

    private void clearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //this will deselect all of the radio buttons, along with clearing the 
        // textboxes with input and output information.
        depositBtn.Checked = false;
        checksBtn.Checked = false;
        serviceBtn.Checked = false;
        inputTxt.Clear();
        outputTxt.Clear();
    }

    private void calculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        // Calculate button actions
        try {
            InputInteger = Convert.ToInt32(inputTxt.Text);
            // For each radio button checked gives an action to the calculate button
            if (depositBtn.Checked == true); {
                OutputInteger = (InputInteger + HoldInteger);
                outputTxt.Text = OutputInteger.ToString();

            } else if (checksBtn.Checked == true); {
                if (InputInteger > OutputInteger); {
                    OutputInteger = (HoldInteger - 10);
                    outputTxt.Text = OutputInteger.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("Insufficient Funds");
                    if (HoldInteger < 0); {
                        MessageBox.Show("Negative account balance");
                    }
                } else if (InputInteger <= HoldInteger); {
                    OutputInteger = (InputInteger - HoldInteger);
                    outputTxt.Text = OutputInteger.ToString();

                }
            } else if (serviceBtn.Checked); {
                if (InputInteger > OutputInteger); {
                    OutputInteger = (HoldInteger - 10);
                    outputTxt.Text = OutputInteger.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("Insufficient Funds");
                    if (HoldInteger < 0); {
                        MessageBox.Show("Negative account balance");
                    }
                } else if (InputInteger <= HoldInteger); {
                    OutputInteger = (InputInteger - HoldInteger);
                    outputTxt.Text = OutputInteger.ToString();

                }
            }
        } catch {

        }

    }

    private void outputTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }
}
}
```

I am not getting any text in my read-only outputTxt textbox. Any help is appreciated. I need the outputTxt to display after each click event of the Calculate button. I have used the HoldInteger to hold intermediary calculations for the outputinteger which should be the final output for each selection of a radio button.[My form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSViz.png)

Comment: Holy crap I feel like an idiot, shouldn't try to write a program with distractions. Thanks a bunch dotnetom!

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove `;` from the end of each `if` statement.

Change

```
if (depositBtn.Checked == true) ;
```

to

```
if (depositBtn.Checked == true)
```

Do it in all places where you used `;` after `if` statement.

This is because if you are using `;` after `if` statement you are effectively adding an empty script block. These codes are basically identical:

```
// this code block
if (depositBtn.Checked == true); 
{
    OutputInteger = (InputInteger + HoldInteger);
    outputTxt.Text = OutputInteger.ToString();
} 

//is identical to
if (depositBtn.Checked == true)
{
}
{
    OutputInteger = (InputInteger + HoldInteger);
    outputTxt.Text = OutputInteger.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine except ; after `if(condition);`
remove all ; just after the conditional statements. and write like `if(condition){}`
then you are good to go.